# no speedup when using numba jit

Tags: python, jit, numba

I am trying to run a NEAT algorithm using [this](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python implementation. This is the original file from the library that is relevant for my question:

```
from neat.graphs import feed_forward_layers


class FeedForwardNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, node_evals):
        self.input_nodes = inputs
        self.output_nodes = outputs
        self.node_evals = node_evals
        self.values = dict((key, 0.0) for key in inputs + outputs)

    def activate(self, inputs):
        if len(self.input_nodes) != len(inputs):
            raise RuntimeError("Expected {0:n} inputs, got {1:n}".format(len(self.input_nodes), len(inputs)))

        for k, v in zip(self.input_nodes, inputs):
            self.values[k] = v

        for node, act_func, agg_func, bias, response, links in self.node_evals:
            node_inputs = []
            for i, w in links:
                node_inputs.append(self.values[i] * w)
            s = agg_func(node_inputs)
            self.values[node] = act_func(bias + response * s)

        return [self.values[i] for i in self.output_nodes]

    @staticmethod
    def create(genome, config):
        """ Receives a genome and returns its phenotype (a FeedForwardNetwork). """

        # Gather expressed connections.
        connections = [cg.key for cg in genome.connections.values() if cg.enabled]

        layers = feed_forward_layers(config.genome_config.input_keys, config.genome_config.output_keys, connections)
        node_evals = []
        for layer in layers:
            for node in layer:
                inputs = []
                node_expr = [] # currently unused
                for conn_key in connections:
                    inode, onode = conn_key
                    if onode == node:
                        cg = genome.connections[conn_key]
                        inputs.append((inode, cg.weight))
                        node_expr.append("v[{}] * {:.7e}".format(inode, cg.weight))

                ng = genome.nodes[node]
                aggregation_function = config.genome_config.aggregation_function_defs.get(ng.aggregation)
                activation_function = config.genome_config.activation_defs.get(ng.activation)
                node_evals.append((node, activation_function, aggregation_function, ng.bias, ng.response, inputs))

        return FeedForwardNetwork(config.genome_config.input_keys, config.genome_config.output_keys, node_evals)
```

Since I evaluate the performance of my neural networks on a large dataset, I wanted to speed up the `activate` method using numba jit. In order to not fall back into numbas object mode I had to update  the implementation of the `activate` method (and hence also the fields of the `FeedForwardNetwork` class) using only datatypes supported by numba. This is what I came up with (`create` is the same as before):

```
from neat.graphs import feed_forward_layers
from neat.six_util import itervalues

import numba
from numba import jit, njit
from numba.typed import List, Dict
import numpy as np
import math


@jit(nopython=True)
def activate(input_nodes, output_nodes, node_evals_node, node_evals_bias, node_evals_resp, node_evals_ins_nodes, node_evals_ins_conns, values, inputs):
    for i in range(input_nodes.size):
        values[input_nodes[i]] = inputs[i]

    for node in range(len(node_evals_node)):
        s = 0
        for pred in range(len(node_evals_ins_nodes[node])):
            s += values[node_evals_ins_nodes[node][pred]] * node_evals_ins_conns[node][pred]

        values[node_evals_node[node]] = math.tanh(node_evals_bias[node] + node_evals_resp[node] * s)

    return [values[output_nodes[i]] for i in range(output_nodes.size)]


class FeedForwardNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, node_evals):
        self.input_nodes = np.array(inputs)
        self.output_nodes = np.array(outputs)

        # NODE_EVALS decomposition
        self.node_evals_node = np.reshape(np.array(node_evals)[:, 0:1], (len(node_evals),)).astype(np.int64)
        self.node_evals_bias = np.reshape(np.array(node_evals)[:, 3:4], (len(node_evals),)).astype(np.float64)
        self.node_evals_resp = np.reshape(np.array(node_evals)[:, 4:5], (len(node_evals),)).astype(np.float64)

        temp = np.array(node_evals)[:, 5:6]

        self.node_evals_ins_nodes = List()
        self.node_evals_ins_conns = List()

        for node in range(temp.size):
            l = List()
            m = List()

            for predecessor in range(len(temp[node])):
                l.append(temp[0][node][predecessor][0])
                m.append(temp[0][node][predecessor][1])

            self.node_evals_ins_nodes.append(l)
            self.node_evals_ins_conns.append(m)

        self.values = Dict()
        # Set types of dict
        self.values[0] = float(1)
        self.values.pop(0)
```

This is the code I call the `create` and `activate` method in:

```
def eval_single_genome(genome, config, thread_id, result):
    net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome, config)

    error_sum = 0

    for i, row in PRICES.iterrows():
        prediction = feed_forward.activate(net.input_nodes, net.output_nodes, net.node_evals_node, net.node_evals_bias, net.node_evals_resp, net.node_evals_ins_nodes, net.node_evals_ins_conns, net.values, np.array([0]))
        error_sum += (prediction - PRICES.iloc[i]['open']) ** 2

    result[thread_id] = error_sum
```

The code compiles and runs without errors or warnings which (as far as I've understood) indicates that numba should be able to optimize my implementation. But adding/removing the `@jit(nopython=True)`decorator doesn't change the runtime at all.

Did I overlook something? Or is there just nothing that numba can improve in my case?

Comment: Did you find a reason for no speedup?

Comment: No. Ended up using c++ instead of python.

Comment: Would be very nice to see